# How can I get the Delivery Status Notification from MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) like Exim, using Javamail library?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, exim, exim4

I'm asking here if there is a way to ask a MTA (like EXIM) for

Delivery Status Notifications through Javamail library, as i know there is a class

called DeliveryStatus in javamail but i can't figure out how to use it in order to

get DSN from EXIM. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 1891](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1891.txt) describes how to request a Delivery Status Notification and the [com.sun.mail.smtp package javadocs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) describe the [mail.smtp.dsn.notify](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.dsn.notify) and [mail.smtp.dsn.ret](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.dsn.ret) properties you can set corresponding to the features in RFC 1891.  You can also use the [SMTPMessage](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPMessage.html) class, which contains methods to set these [notification](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPMessage.html#setNotifyOptions-int-) [options](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPMessage.html#setReturnOption-int-).